# When to write different functions and when to use the same function with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

In other words, when should I write this?

```
_.insertUp = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 0, newObj)
}

_.insertDown = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)
}

_.insertUpDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  const found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) _.insertUp(found, obj, newObj)
  return arr
}

_.insertDownDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  const found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) _.insertDown(found, obj, newObj)
  return arr
}
```

And when should I write this?

```
_.insert = (pos, arr, obj, newObj) => {
  if (pos === 'up') return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 0, newObj)
  if (pos === 'down') return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)
}

_.insertDown = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)
}

_.insertUpDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  const found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) _.insert('up', found, obj, newObj)
  return arr
}

_.insertDownDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  const found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) _.insert('down', found, obj, newObj)
  return arr
}
```

(I think libraries like jQuery tend to go with the first example? e.g. `append` and `prepend`.)

Comment: The first API seems a lot more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

it is about giving yourself flexibility while keeping your code organized and your functions small and readable.
The first example does that and it follows the guidelines of writing functions to do one thing, so even if you need the a function from the second example it should be like this:

```
_.insertUp = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 0, newObj)
}

_.insertDown = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  return arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)

_.insert = (pos, arr, obj, newObj) => {
  if (pos === 'up') return insertUp(arr, obj, newObj)
  if (pos === 'down') return insertDown (arr, obj, newObj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to consider how the functions appear in the code where they are used.  If you have `insertUp(...)` it kind of makes sense and it's not easy to call the function incorrectly.

When you have `insert('up'...)` then you are introducing a sort of *magical parameter* of 'up'.  When you look at that code you have to wonder what other values are acceptable.  You can guess that 'down' is probably acceptable. Is 'left' or 'right' an acceptable value?  What about 'UP'?  What's going to happen if you pass a value the function doesn't like?  Who knows.  The code is harder to understand when you are looking at the code where the function is called.